# 4-bit IC to 8-bit RAM module

Tags: circuit-design, ram, module

I'm trying to wire up a RAM module based on the Ben Eater's RAM Module Part 1 video, but there are no available RAM chips where I'm located at so the only IC I have available is a CAT22C10 NVRAM which I think is more than enough (256-bit in 64 x 4-bit words). I could buy two and set them in parallel but I think that's a waste since a single one can handle more than the 16 bytes I'm targeting to. I've been thinking about placing two 74HC173s in a low nibble/high nibble configuration but I'm short of ideas on how to build up a byte out of the 4-bit CAT22C10.

Comment: From [the diagram](https://eater.net/8bit/ram), the man himself shied away from using a single 64×4 RAM this way and went with two. I'd take that as a hint: One would need a *sequencer* to handle nibble ↔ byte conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Your module gives you 4 bit at a time; so, you'd first need to have a local clock two times the rate of the SRAM interface clock; that alone might be quite limiting, since that thing needs 300 ns per read, so that's 0.6 µs for a double-nibble read, or conversely a maximum interface speed of 1600 kHz.

You would wire the address lines coming from whatever you use this emulated SRAM with such that they define A1…A6, and would toggle A0 one each clock cycle, while using muxes to select the matching quad latch (or flipflop) connected to the matching set of 4 lines from the data lines.

That seems to be a bad trade-off in speed and complexity, and I'd look whether I couldn't build a 256 bit memory directly out of 74xx ICs. If you went with 74xx574 ICs, you'd get a byte of register each, a clock input and an output enable that you can use to select the active byte. You need 32 of that to get your 256 bit addressable in 8-bit words, meaning you need a simple 5-bit address decoder logic only. That feels simpler than to create a multi-clock system.

Comment: (256 bit is what both the CAT22C10 and the 74189 in the original schematic/BOM offer, just 16×8 are used.)

Comment: Something was telling me this was a bad idea but still I spent like 2 days thinking about it before I asked here, thank you for your time.

Comment: @deltakid0 it honestly depends on what you're trying to do, and what clocks you have at hand. If it's easy for you to add a sequence of two reads and assemble them into a byte each time the request line (or however it's called in your context) is asserted, well, you can do that in less than 32 chips :) if you want to build something simple, well-debuggable and easy to explain, flat byte-addressable memory can be built from scratch, as I explained, but if built on 74xx, it will need a lot of chips. Trade-offs!